# Django Query using contains with a list as a source?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of postcodes for example:-

```
postcodes = ['LDN 4DN','MAN 4RF']
```

The address field has the post code in it, sample address fields are

'1 downing street, London, England, LDN 4DN'
'10 the avenues, Manchester, England, MAN 4RF'
'20 the Highalnds, Scotland, SCT L40'

Im using

```
site = SiteData.objects.filter(address__icontains=postcodes[0]))
```

In a loop to get each site, but that seems a bit lengthy, is it possible to do contains in?

can i run a query to get for example the records for the two postcodes in the list?

Thanks

Comment: I've modified your question to make it slightly clearer what the issue is. feel free to roll back if this is incorrect

Comment: hi i don tneed it to be case insentive? the question was how i can use contains and in, in the same query.

Comment: `icontains` is a case insensitive contains, contains on its own is what `in` essentially does anyway

Comment: ive edtited to try make the question more clear

Comment: Oh right I see now, then bruno's answer is the only way I believe

Comment: "`contains` on its own is what `in` essentially does anyway" - err, quite not actually. `field__contains='xxx'` translates to a `field like "%xxx%"` (mysql syntax) clause, while `field__in=("a", "b", "c")` translates to a standard SQL in clause, ie `field in("a", "b", "c")` - which is logically equivalent to `(field = 'a' or field = 'b' or field='c')`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That wont work, obviously - but you can use `models.Q` to build a "or" query:

```
import operator

clauses = (Q(address__icontains=p) for p in postcodes)
query = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
site = SiteData.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django's Overlap filter to achieve this.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap):

> Returns objects where the data shares any results with the values passed. Uses the SQL operator &&.

So, you could try:

```
site = SiteData.objects.filter(address__overlap=postcodes))
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for PostgreSQL.

Comment: It should also be noted this only works with Array type fields.